# Connecting Azure DevOps to Azure machine learning studio

Tags: azure, machine-learning, mlops

I am trying to create a ARM template for my MLOps project and everytime i run a setup pipeline to create it i receive this error : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U0u5.png)

I double checked my credentials and the variables and searched carefully for mistakes in the json file and yet i couldn't find any..
here's the json file :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "baseName": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 10,
      "minLength": 3,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The base name to use as prefix to create all the resources."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "eastus",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "workspace": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storageAccount": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(toLower(parameters('baseName')), 'amlsa')]"
    },
    "keyvault": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(parameters('baseName'),'-AML-KV')]"
    },
    "appInsights": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(parameters('baseName'),'-AML-AI')]"
    },
    "acr": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(toLower(parameters('baseName')),'amlcr')]"
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "basic",
      "allowedValues": [
        "basic",
        "enterprise"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the sku, also referred as 'edition' of the Azure Machine Learning workspace."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "amlWorkspaceName": "[parameters('workspace')]",
    "storageAccountName": "[parameters('storageAccount')]",
    "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS",
    "keyVaultName": "[parameters('keyvault')]",
    "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
    "applicationInsightsName": "[parameters('appInsights')]",
    "containerRegistryName": "[parameters('acr')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2018-07-01",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[variables('storageAccountType')]"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "properties": {
        "encryption": {
          "services": {
            "blob": {
              "enabled": true
            },
            "file": {
              "enabled": true
            }
          },
          "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
        },
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
      "name": "[variables('keyVaultName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "tenantId": "[variables('tenantId')]",
        "sku": {
          "name": "standard",
          "family": "A"
        },
        "accessPolicies": [
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
      "name": "[variables('applicationInsightsName')]",
      "location": "[if(or(equals(parameters('location'),'eastus2'),equals(parameters('location'),'westcentralus')),'southcentralus',parameters('location'))]",
      "kind": "web",
      "properties": {
        "Application_Type": "web"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries",
      "apiVersion": "2017-10-01",
      "name": "[variables('containerRegistryName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard"
      },
      "properties": {
        "adminUserEnabled": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-19",
      "name": "[variables('amlWorkspaceName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyVaultName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries', variables('containerRegistryName'))]"
      ],
      "identity": {
        "type": "systemAssigned"
      },
      "sku": {
        "tier": "[parameters('sku')]",
        "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "friendlyName": "[variables('amlWorkspaceName')]",
        "keyVault": "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults',variables('keyVaultName'))]",
        "applicationInsights": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components',variables('applicationInsightsName'))]",
        "containerRegistry": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries',variables('containerRegistryName'))]",
        "storageAccount": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/',variables('storageAccountName'))]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

PLEASE HELP!!!!